# change ip location with python request and proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, proxy, request

I ve searched on the Internet how to find free proxy servers, how to use it, BUT even when I use the proxy (it takes really more time with proxy), it seems that the websites can still see the real ip adress (for example, a request to https://ipinfo.io will show your real ip). I know that there are other factors like the cache etc... But is there a universal solution that we can add to the script?

```
proxies = {
  'http': 'http://proxy:port',
  'https': 'http://proxy:port'
}

response = requests.get('http://ipinfo.io/json', proxies=proxies)

print(response.content)
```

I tried with the requests module, with urllib.request also, but with the same results. Is there something wrong, or something I forgot?

Comment: You haven't shown us how you're setting the `proxies` variable. Without that information we can't tell why things aren't working.

Comment: Please share your full codes and including how you hit the https://ipinfo.io or https://ipaddress.my to get the IP address.

Comment: it's done, i edited

Comment: no answers? nobody?

Comment: please people, up!